# How to center a text nav bar with CSS

Tags: html, css, text, navigation

My text navigation bar keeps pulling to the left, can anyone tell me if my code is wrong somewhere? I've tried inline-block and removed float but it's still not working!

```
#navigation ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
width:400px;
margin:auto;
display: inline-block;}

#navigation li {
margin: 1em 1em;
font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Calibri, GillSans, sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
display: inline-block;}

#navigation li a {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
}

#content {
width: 960px;
margin-top: 25px;
text-align:center;
}

#footer {
margin-top:30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0.9em;
}

#sub_navigation {
color: #BBB;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom: 25px;
height:55px;
letter-spacing:5px;
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="navigation" class="span-24 last">
        <ul>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="editorial.html">Editorial</a></li>
<li><a href="portraits.html">Portraits</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `display:inline-block` property for `ul` to center this : and for the items add `text-align`

```
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
  /*display: inline-block;*/ ---> Remove this
 text-align: center; ----> Add this
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/aYVAP/2/**

Comment: that made my nav bar vertical instead of horizontal but it was centralized

Comment: don't remove the display:inline block for the li elements just the ul like i post

Comment: i didn't Danko, only for Ul

Comment: mmm can you make a fiddle ?? because if sou see my demo i copy paste your code and works fine... or try adding to the ul white-space:nowrap;

Answer (score 0):

Delete display:inline-block in --->

```
#navigation li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 **display: inline-block;**
}
```

Paste: **`text-align:center;`**